# How to determine the signal direction in Altium Schematic?

Tags: signal, schematics, altium, button, digital-input

I have 5 signals as digital input. We can think of them as a simple button. They hook up to PCB via a connector on the card and I want to show them as a port in the Schematic. How can I determine their signal directions as correct?

[image]

I think drawing port direction depends on current direction. Is that make sense or not?

[image]

Comment: Signal direction is semantics. For a current, there is direction. For a voltage, for example, appearing on a bus, you can have a source as output and sinks as input, but sticking a probe and measuring the voltage, you will just get a voltage and the signal direction is whatever you determine it to be. Could you give some more information on our signal and why it needs to be determined if it's an input or output? Are you referring to the setting in Altium on signal direction or is your question general?

Comment: Actually, I try to form a standard myself in Altium. These signals were defined as digital inputs in the requirement list.

Comment: I've worked my way around that Altium feature to have it look for outputs being connected to inputs and nothing else so I'm not the right person to answer. For a digital only board, I can see how the feature would be good for DRC, for a very mixed environment, I get warnings fatigue (see MFA fatigue) and just ignore them.

Answer (score 0):

In Altium, when you draw a port symbol and open its properties, you'll see a drop-down box for "I/O Type."

[image]

In that drop-down you can select the direction of the signal.  Note that this is a logical direction, and so if you have an Input-type port assigned, then somewhere there needs to be an Output-type port that drives that input, or you'll get an error.  The error isn't fatal, more of a nuisance.